# При слове "диск" не открывается файл по заданному пути

Tags: python, subprocess, распознавание-речи

Всегда открывается одна и та же папка в диске C: (не помню какая, вроде юзерс), и на путь вообще не реагирует. Файл в диске точно есть. пробовал вроде с помощью sys, но тоже самое

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import subprocess

print("Если вы захотите выйти, то просто скажите.")

while True:
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=2) as source:
        print("Скажи что-то...")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")
    if query == "диск":
        subprocess.Popen('explorer "D:\1.jpg"') 
    else:
        print("Ты сказал: " + query.lower())
```

Comment: А почему эксплорер должен картинку открывать?  Ну и, мне кажется там второго бэкслеша не хватает.

Comment: не только картинку, даже когда просто путь указываю например: D:\m\ (Открыть папку "m") то всё равно диск C:

Comment: Только что попробовал с открытием именно папки, поставить второй бэкслеш. Всё работает! А можете подсказать что использовать для того, чтобы открывать именно файлы (.exe к примеру)

Comment: Почитайте документацию на класс `Popen()`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor